# find a partial text in vector row +[r]

Tags: r

Basically I'm looking to write a function that will take a vector of strings and a search term as input, and output a boolean vector. After this, I'd also like to take a list of strings and run it through this same function to output multiple results vectors, one for each string.

So the initial data looks like:

```
> searchVector <- cbind(c("aaa1","aaa2","","bbb1,aaa1,ccc1", "ddd1,ccc1,aaa1"))
> searchVector
     [,1]         
[1,] "aaa1"        
[2,] "aaa2"        
[3,] ""           
[4,] "bbb1,aaa1,ccc1"
[5,] "ddd1,ccc1,aaa1"
```

and this is what we'd hope to see:

```
>findTrigger(c("aaa","bbb"),searchVector)
         [aaa]  [bbb]
    [1,] 1     0   
    [2,] 1     0   
    [3,] 0     0      
    [4,] 1     1
    [5,] 1     0
```

I've made the following attempt:

```
searchfunction <- function (searchTerms, searchVector) {
  output = matrix( nrow = length(searchVector), 
             ncol = length(searchTerms), 
             dimnames = searchTerms)

  for (j in seq(1,length(searchTerms)))
  {
    for (i in seq(1,length(searchVector)))
    { 
      output[i,j]=is.numeric(pmatch(searchTerms[j], searchVector[i]))
    }
  }
  return(as.numeric(output))
}
```

But I just get a matrix of all 1's. I'm fairly new to R and I've looked around online, but haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapply` and `grep` or `grepl` (thanks joran) are your friend:

```
searchTerms <- c("aaa", "bbb")
searchVector <- cbind(c("aaa1","aaa2","","bbb1,aaa1,ccc1", "ddd1,ccc1,aaa1"))
M <- mapply(grepl, searchTerms, MoreArgs=list(x=searchVector)) 
M
       aaa   bbb
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE    
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE
```

If you want it as `1,0`: `apply(M,2,as.numeric)`

Comment: This is perfect - I went over the documentation for mapply, grep and grepl and was blown away by how simply it was! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use the function `grepl`. This should get you started:

```
searchVector <- c("aaa1","aaa2","","bbb1,aaa1,ccc1", "ddd1,ccc1,aaa1")

res <- lapply(c('aaa','bbb'),function(pattern,x) as.numeric(grepl(pattern = pattern,x = x)),x = searchVector)
do.call(cbind,res)
```

To explore this a bit, start with just `grepl`:

```
> grepl('aaa',searchVector)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> as.numeric(grepl('aaa',searchVector))
[1] 1 1 0 1 1
```

Then I'm just wrapping that up in `lapply`, to loop over the vector `c('aaa','bbb')`. This will return a list of vectors, which we then combine into the matrix you indicated using `do.call` and `cbind`.